# adding image to post thumbnail from another server

Tags: images, uploads, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

i have a image gallery site, each post in site have thumbnail and image in post, now i want get *file server* for uploaded image.
how can i add thumb image from another server? or how can i change the destination image uploader to file server?
or any other solution.
tnx 4 adv.

Comment: Which another server you are referring to? CDN, Different domain/subdomain on same web host or different web hosting provider?

Comment: @Roberthue different web hosting provider accessing with ip, not domain

Comment: @Roberthue i check my hosting and possible use sub domain for file server

Comment: If you can use subdomain or domain on same server then it's easy. Just change upload location in WordPress admin and set URLs accordingly. I will post more detailed answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was writing a guide but then I found a tutorial for this.
Follow this tutorial to setup subdomain for uploaded files.

http://www.dezzain.com/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-uploads-path-to-subdomain/

Comment: tnx :) after doing this i must copy current image to new location on file server or this not any effect on old post?

Comment: Yes, it will not move older files automatically. You will have to move those first. All new files will be automatically uploaded to new location.